# Set UWP NavigationViewItem Icon from code behind

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I want to be able to dynamically add NavigationViewItems in my UWP app, but I can't figure out how to set the icons.

NavigationViewItem.Icon in XAML is formatted: `Icon="Page"`, which looks like it's using the `Symbol` enum. Except C# says that it's an `IconElement` object

I want to be able to write something like this:

```
NavigationViewItem navItem = new NavigationViewItem();
navItem.Icon = Symbol.Page;
navView.MenuItems.Add(navItem)
```

The compiler spits an error at `Symbol.Page` because it's not an IconElement, is there any way I can convert it to an IconElement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The XAML syntax in this case creates the [IconElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.iconelement) for you automatically when the XAML is compiled. When you do it from code you need to create it manually. There is a [SymbolIcon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.symbolicon) class that inherits from [IconElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.iconelement) that does the same in code. Check also the documentation for [IconElement derived classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.iconelement#iconelement-derived-classes) to see all the possible icon types.

Here is also the fixed code:

```
NavigationViewItem navItem = new NavigationViewItem();
navItem.Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.Page);
navView.MenuItems.Add(navItem);
```